# nacl crypto installation on arch

Tags: arch-linux, hostname, cryptography

I am trying to install [nacl crypto](http://nacl.cace-project.eu/install.html) on my system:

```
% uname -a
Linux (none) 2.6.39-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 6 22:37:55 CEST 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M 540 @ 2.53GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

But the build process didn't succeed:

```
~/nacl-20110221 % ./do
./do: line 9: hostname: command not found
```

Did I forget something?

**[update]**

```
% cat /etc/hosts
#
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#

#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost
# End of file
```

Comment: Are you using the AUR PKGBUILD? https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=44277

Comment: no, i'll check that.

Comment: [update] this isn't working either since makepkg loads the tar.bz2, unzips it and intends to execute ./do

Comment: Does your machine have a hostname? That seems to be required by NaCl: "All compilation takes place in a host-specific subdirectory"

Comment: the hostname value in rc.conf seems to be set. i updated the question and i've inserted the /etc/host output

Comment: No - you have no hostname. It should look like: "127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost _yourhostname_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the `hostname` command. It [just moved from `net-tools` to `coreutils`](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/24627), so make sure you have the latest `coreutils`. Though there is [some debate as to whether this is right](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/24651), so it might change again.

As of 2020, the package containing `hostname` [is now `inetutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/).